# Require behaves differently in Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, require, webpack-file-loader

If to write something like `const theoretically = require('jasmine-theories');`, **require** returns the content of the file.
But if to set `declare var require: any;`, then next `**require**` executions steps inside webpack bootstrap `function __webpack_require__(moduleId)` and return real file path with hash, not content (for example **'file.65465436547.js'**).

I've found out that file-loader has such behavior https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader .

I may assume that depending on `declare var require: any;` **require** is taken from **NodeJS** or from **File-loader**.

Is that correct? And is there more obvious way how and when to use each of them?

And how can I config File-loader to behave another way in case of Angular application? **Angular CLI** doesn't provide **webpack.config**, therefore loaders just get installed without any configuration possible.

Overall the question can be shortened to:

**Why require returns content in one case and file name in another case?**

Comment: because the main method is exported as default. [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/blob/d016daa76458588acb15cac900686b7990c4f574/src/index.js#L8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that before `declare var require: any;` default method is used from Node JS. But after explicit declaring FileLoader's method becomes visible. And as it has default exporting - require usage is switched to FileLoader's one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use require, use

```
import { theoretically } from 'jasmine-theories';
```

This is webpack tree shakable.

Comment: It is just an example. The question is in another. Why require returns content in one case and file name in another case?